# Water coming out of Teddys toy-gun in the lighthouse scene

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, shutter-island

In *Shutter Island* there's water coming out of the toy-gun in the lighthouse scene as he breaks it in two pieces.

You can see it here:

So I've tried googling and read a lot about the meaning of water & fire so I'm assuming this is connected to that but I'm not entirely sure. What are your takes on this detail?

Comment: I think you are putting too much meaning into such a detail - IMO the dripping water from the gun is just to enforce the fact that the gun is fake

Comment: He'd just swum across to the lighthouse; though he'd been out of the water maybe 10 mins by that time, just perhaps it's water dripping from him. I'll admit it doesn't really make much sense as the gun itself was on the desk for the whole scene & he'd been holding it just a few seconds. (I'm not sure I can turn that into an actual answer, as I can't see the logic in it myself) though we are aware by that point that what **he** sees is not necessarily reliable, including that he just shot the doc.